# Major Problems with HTML signature and outlook 2010

Tags: html, outlook-2010, thunderbird

I have just purchased a service called WiseStamp for email signature templates.  When i test the templates in Outlook2010 they don't render properly, infact the formatting is hopeless!

Can someone please have a look at my code?  It works fine in web browser and perfect in Thunderbird and it's driving me mad!

```
    <div style="font-family: sans-serif; line-height: 15px; width: 440px; empty-cells: show;">
<div style="font-family: sans-serif; line-height: 15px; text-transform: capitalize; border-bottom-color: #B8B8B8; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: dashed; padding-bottom: 4px; width: 440px; empty-cells: show;"><span class="text-color" style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 17.3333px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 21px; text-transform: capitalize; color: #eb1c23; border-color: #eb1c23; empty-cells: show;">Guy Rogers</span><img style="font-family: sans-serif; line-height: 15px; text-transform: capitalize; height: 50px; width: 200px; display: block; float: right; empty-cells: show;" src="http://bn1.so/radarone/radaronelogo.png" alt="" /><br style="font-family: sans-serif; line-height: 15px; text-transform: capitalize; width: 0px; empty-cells: show;" /> <span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">Director , Radar One Ltd</span>&nbsp;</div>
<table style="font-family: sans-serif; line-height: 15px; width: 440px; empty-cells: show; border-color: #000000;" border="0">
<tbody style="font-family: sans-serif; line-height: 15px; width: 436px; border-spacing: 2px 2px; empty-cells: show; border-color: #000000;">
<tr style="font-family: sans-serif; line-height: 15px; width: 436px; border-spacing: 2px 2px; empty-cells: show; border-color: #000000;" valign="top">
<td style="font-family: 'Times New Roman',georgia,serif; font-style: italic; line-height: 15px; vertical-align: top; color: #828282; padding-top: 1px; padding-right: 25px; padding-bottom: 1px; padding-left: 1px; width: 410px; border-spacing: 2px 2px; empty-cells: show; border-color: #828282;">
<div style="font-family: sans-serif; font-style: italic; line-height: 15px; color: #828282; width: 410px; border-spacing: 2px 2px; empty-cells: show; border-color: #828282;"><span style="font-size: small;"><strong class="text-color" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-style: italic; line-height: 15px; color: #eb1c23; border-spacing: 2px 2px; empty-cells: show; border-color: #EB1C23;">t.</strong> 01273 806484</span></div>
<div style="font-family: sans-serif; font-style: italic; line-height: 15px; color: #828282; width: 410px; border-spacing: 2px 2px; empty-cells: show; border-color: #828282;"><span style="font-size: small;"><strong class="text-color" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-style: italic; line-height: 15px; color: #eb1c23; border-spacing: 2px 2px; empty-cells: show; border-color: #EB1C23;">m.</strong> 07786 546 230</span></div>
<div style="font-family: sans-serif; font-style: italic; line-height: 15px; color: #828282; width: 410px; border-spacing: 2px 2px; empty-cells: show; border-color: #828282;"><span style="font-size: small;"><strong class="text-color" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-style: italic; line-height: 15px; color: #eb1c23; border-spacing: 2px 2px; empty-cells: show; border-color: #EB1C23;">e.</strong> guy.rogers@radarone.co.uk</span></div>
<div style="font-family: sans-serif; font-style: italic; line-height: 15px; color: #828282; width: 410px; border-spacing: 2px 2px; empty-cells: show; border-color: #828282;"><span style="font-size: small;"><strong class="text-color" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-style: italic; line-height: 15px; color: #eb1c23; border-spacing: 2px 2px; empty-cells: show; border-color: #EB1C23;">w.</strong> http://www.radarone.co.uk</span></div>
<div style="font-family: sans-serif; font-style: italic; line-height: 15px; color: #828282; width: 410px; border-spacing: 2px 2px; empty-cells: show; border-color: #828282;"><span style="font-size: small;"><strong class="text-color" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-style: italic; line-height: 15px; color: #eb1c23; border-spacing: 2px 2px; empty-cells: show; border-color: #EB1C23;">a.</strong> Albert House, 82 Queens Road, Brighton, East Sussex, BN1 3TL</span></div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook has many HTML and CSS no-no's

check out: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/ to see if you can find what part of your code is creating the problem

Comment: Hi Adsy, thanks for your response. Had a look on CampaignMonitor, looks very resourceful and I am certainly going to read some more as I am trying to brush up on my HTML for e-shots and other marketing stuff! 

In the short term, I am struggling because I purchased these signature templates so that I could avoid coding at this stage - I am very out of touch!

Could you perhaps drop me a couple of hints as to why this could be happening to my code?

Thanks again for engaging ^_^

Comment: Hi @afro, Happy to try my best and help out. I'm not sure 100% but it may be the "style" you're using in your divs. It's hard to tell just by looking at what goes wrong with email clients and coding as they vary, and I know Outlook has a tendency to play up with some coding (I know this from recently using Outlook myself for email forms). all I know is that some CSS and html codes tend to play up so never just go by what your browser looks like. It's a case of trial and error. Also as no-one else has responded, would you mind voting my answer as best choice? :)

Comment: Hi @Adsy, thanks for your response!  Here is a link to the html file so you can see how it looks in the browser. It surprises me that Outlook is so difficult compared to other email clients for HTML, but most businesses use outlook on ms exchange so it's a real surprise that it's so difficult to get an html signature embedded!  I will certainly vote your answer, just need to figure out how to do it ;)

Comment: You've not posted the link :( to vote, just click the tick next to my answer :)

Comment: I'm so sorry! I forgot to paste the link with all the excitement! :-) http://bn1.so/radarone/signature.html

Comment: not to worry! Could you also post an image of how it looks in outlook too? just so I can see how it gets messed up

Comment: Hi again, sure here is a link to the problem, it seems to be stretching across the page now.  previously the image was overlapping the name/title area but I have managed to move it - http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/825/kfnt.png/

Comment: Just looking at the code and I noticed that the "radar one" image is align="right" what happens if you align="left"? does that move the image back over to the text?

Comment: Tried that, it moves the image to the far left which interferes with the name/title, i've included a screenshot to show you.  That's probably the main issue, and that the width of the signature is much wider than in the original html http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/716/bg43.png

Comment: Can you post a new jsfiddle with the code you are using now please?

Comment: Yea it is a very nifty thing :)

Right, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/DtQbb/1/
I set the signature in a table and set the width to be fixed so hopefully that doesn't force out the signature. hopefully that does it.

Comment: Hi again, thank you so much, really appreciate your help! i've tried it and it's almost perfect, I was wondering if you could help me tweak the position of the logo so it's flush above the dotted-line if possible? I tried but i broke it slightly but I have undone back to how it was. here is what it looks like now in Outlook - http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/692/yczl.png/  | And here is the jsfiddle(love this!) http://jsfiddle.net/xHSF2/  - Any thoughts on what to do? Thanks again

Comment: Hehe, it's so fiddly isn't it, i'm shocked that Outlook isn't conforming to standards of other less-popular email clients! Here is the latest compile = http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/30/gkef.png/

Comment: Morning Adsy, how are you?  Sorry for the late reply, I had to shut down and then I have been away this weekend.

Comment: I tried the latest code from your jsfiddle, and this is what came up, which is real close now! I was wondering if you would be able to have a quick look? http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/839/w921.png @Adsy